# why won't my css or js apply in firefox?

Tags: html, css, mozilla

My webpage works fine in chrome, internet explorer, and JSFiddle but when opened in Mozilla it doesn't read any link or script tags except the ones linked to a website, i.e jquery. In the developer tools it reads jquery but no other JS and says there are no styles applied to the webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Word Master</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Users/Thomas/OneDrive/Documents/workPlease/WMstyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Thomas/OneDrive/Documents/workPlease/WMfunctions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Thomas/OneDrive/Documents/workPlease/errorCheck.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Thomas/OneDrive/Documents/workPlease/WMpopups.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Thomas/OneDrive/Documents/workPlease/WMeasy.js"></script>
</head>
```

I tried saving all of them with encoding UTF-8 and I added `@charset "UTF-8";` to the top of my css.

Comment: Look in the browser console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you are using the `filesystem` path:

```
C:/Users/Thomas/OneDrive/Documents/workPlease/WMeasy.js
```

It should be absolute

```
/workPlease/WMeasy.js
```

or relative

```
WMeasy.js
```